# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot instantiate class EDRTermsPackge.ContactInformationTesting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I"m trying to resolve this issue but to no avail. Here is my Source Code

```
public class ContactInformationTesting   {

    //Using or Launching Internet Explorer
    String exePath = "\\Users\\jj85274\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe";

    //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 




  @Test
  public void OpenPage_Login() {


        driver.get("http://cp-qa.harriscomputer.com/");
  }
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.ie.driver system property;

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the **System** property **webdriver.ie.driver** before instantiating the InternetExplorerDriver object. I could not find that in your code: 
Try following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "<path_to_your_IEDriverServer.exe>");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Let me know, if you still get the same error.

**UPDATE:** I have assumed that **IEDriverServer.exe**'s local path is C:\Users\jj85274\Desktop\IEDriverServer.exe. You can change it, as per its location on your machine. Try following code and let me know, whether you are able to launch Internet Explorer successfully.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\jj85274\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: When I place into my public class, My Code Turns red stating "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"

Comment: This is my updated Source Code

 //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", exePath);

 //Using or Launching Internet Explorer
 String exePath = "\\Users\\jj85274\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe";
 

 //For use of IE only; Please enable for IE Browser
 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

Comment: In your code, you have used variable **exePath** before declaring it. Additionally, the path value specified in **exePath** variable is neither relative nor absolute. I would suggest you to first specify the absolute path value for **IEDriverServer.exe** and check whether you are able to launch Internet Explorer successfully. Please see my update answer above. Once, the Internet Explorer can be launched successfully, you can specify the relative path.

Comment: Thank you very much